# How to compile a non-free ko-file (driver) into kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

1. How to compile a non-free ko-file into kernel? Only the ko-file is provided, but no sources! In addition the kernel does **not** support modules, so the ko-file needs to be loaded, while compiling instead of building from source.
2. Would the compiling disagree GNU GPL?

Comment: Can you explain in details about your question? I am not getting what your are asking.

Comment: What is the kernel module name ?

Answer (score 1):

1. ko-file is an already compiled file - it's a kernel module binary file ready to be loaded into a kernel. If you don't have a source code for the ko-file, there is nothing to be compiled.
2. Please read [GNU GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html). AFAIU It allows you to compile your code using kernel's headers. But if your code is not under GPL, it can't include kernel code parts, it just can call kernel functions and use kernel headers. Note that there are lots of functions in linux kernel that exports with `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL()` that allows you to use these functions only if your code is under GPL too (your kernel module declares `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL")`).

Comment: Of course one may abuse this for private use. Other than that, there are also plenty of functions that are declared as `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` to be used in any kind of modules. Most know ones are GPU drivers (non-Intel).